# Cordova - InApp Broswer - No back button

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am using cordova InApp Broswer (Web View).
When I click on a link, sometimes it gives me a back button, other times it doesn't.

Can someone tell me how I get a back button for all my links ?

Answer (score 0):

When opening the link in InAppBrowser, pass location to yes

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank, "location=yes)
```

Then it will always show your navigation bar and with it the back button